# Does Steam have an account game update history log?

Tags: steam

Does Steam have a local or online log for the updates downloaded to the games installed on your PC? Preferably one that lists technical stuff like manifest id/build id.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to see the changes of a game, each one of them shows different information:

### Changelog for recent updates

The [Your Games & Software](https://store.steampowered.com/updated/myapps/) section of [Recently Updated](https://store.steampowered.com/updated/) shows simple changelogs written by the developers.

[image]

### Changelog for old updates

If you want to search for old updates, you can try the News section of a game, with the filter of Official Announcements enabled.

[image]

## Technical information (size, files changed, hashes, etc.)

If you want the technical information of the update on the other hand, you can try SteamDB. First, go to https://steamdb.info and search for the application or game that you are looking for. After that, you should see a window like this one:

[image]

On the top right area, click Patchnotes. You should see something like this:

[image]

Over there you can select the day of the update to get the technical changes of it, like the manifest, build id and the files that got changed:

[image]

Comment: This is helpful, but I'm afraid I'm looking for a local log to find manifests that steamdb hasn't recorded.

Comment: All of the Steam logs are located at C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\logs, maybe start looking there? Also if is public, SteamDB is going to have it indexed.

Comment: I'll have a look in the logs folder. SteamDB does tend to have everything, but I think older (or removed) manifests are an exception. You can find depots that were definitely  released on a certain date - but you can't find manifests on that date.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like old log entries are auto-deleted.

Comment: If you really want to go all-out on finding those changes, follow the steps [on this answer that I posted on February](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/334861/199843) to see how a Steam game can be downgraded. Then, just compare the changes with external tools.

Comment: That's what I intend to do once I find the manifest, but the problem is steamdb doesn't have all manifests...

Comment: *manifest ID, I should say