# How to downgrade game bought on steam?

Tags: steam

I bought a game on steam (sins of a solar empire: rebellion) and I was using a mod for the game. Now all of a sudden I turn on the computer and start the game and it says that the game automatically updated to version 1.80 (it used to be version 1.52) and the mod doesn't work on 1.80. How do I downgrade the game back to 1.52?

Comment: We already have a question on preventing updates (http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/81470/is-there-any-way-to-stop-steam-downloading-updates), but nothing yet about downgrading. I suggest you refocus the question on just the downgrading part to avoid over-zealous users from attempting to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie hm okay will do. and oh man, I really hope I can downgrade it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only way to "downgrade" a Steam game is to download a Steam backup of the particular version that you want, delete your copy, install the backup and disable automatic updates.

To disable automatic updates for a game, right-click its name in the Steam client's Library tab, then do *Properties* -> *Updates* -> *Do not automatically update this game*.

Note that finding an untouched Steam backup of a game of a particular version can be quite difficult and sharing it may be illegal in your territory. If some of your friends also play that mod and haven't updated yet, you could ask them to make a backup and send it to you.

Comment: Right, thanks. Luckily, I realized I once downloaded and played the game on my pc which I never use so then I just turned on the pc, made sure there was no internet connection so that steam wouldn't automatically start up and install the update, and then I just copied over the files.